# Javascript UI rendering techniques

Tags: javascript, css, dom, user-interface

I'm building an AJAX 'web application' where, once the UI is loaded, calls to the server are for 'data exchange' only. As a result a lot of UI manipulation will be done using Javascript. Lets say the Javascript retrieves some data consisting of multiple fields from the server using AJAX. To put it on the screen I can think of multiple approaches -

1. Call methods like createElement() and appendChild() to build an interface to display the retrieved data
2. Populate the .innerHTML for the container element then for every data field lookup a container in the newly added HTML and populate it. The data that goes into .innerHTML could be stored in a JS variable or contained in a hidden node, or fetched using a seperate AJAX call.
3. Have the interface stored in a hidden node. Clone it (using cloneNode()) and put it in the actual container (using appendChild()) and then populate it with fields like in method 2.

and there are probably more ways.

Could you share pros, cons and possible gotachas in these approaches from cross-browser support, performance and coding complexity point of views?

Somewhat related question: [Is client-side UI rendering via Javascript a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059832/is-client-side-ui-rendering-via-javascript-a-good-idea)

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and its plugins rather than "low-level" calls like createElement() and appendChild().  The upshot is that jQuery takes care of most of the cross-browser compatibility issues for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, let's start off:

### Use toolkits

First you would want to invest time learning a JS toolkit. While others suggest native JS is good (which it really is), but you would not want to waste time on building apps that don't work cross-browser or spend too much time testing it. People in the community have invested their time in doing that for you. Show some love to the open community and use their product. I personally use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but there are others like [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) and [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/).

But still use native JS whenever possible. It's still faster.

### Structure your code

After a toolkit, you need some structure. [BackboneJS](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) will take care of that. It's to structure your code so that your code is reusable and well.. won't end up as spaghetti on your screen. Other tools like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) are also useful for those scripts that need other scripts to run.

### Templates: From strings to elements

Then, with that, you now have a toolkit but you still need to build the interface. It's better if you use a templating engine like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). These render templates for your UI from strings (yes, plain strings of HTML). Just send over your template data from the server, store it in your app (in a variable or browser localstorage), and reuse it as necessary. No need for cloning hidden nodes!

### Don't touch that DOM

As for approaching the DOM, ***you should touch the DOM only when necessary***. DOM is slow, manipulating it is he** slow! that means you should avoid unnecessary animations, avoid excessive element append and remove, as well as changing styles. Check this article about [avoiding too much reflow and repaints](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/). Face it, the user won't event notice the round corners of your boxes, or the gradient background and don't even care if you did a slide animation or a fade-out. What they want is to get the job done and not adore the fireworks display.

Also, remove anything that isn't on screen. You might end up having 20% content on screen, and 80% off screen - a waste of memory.

### Cache: fetch once, store, use infinitely for later

Now, your app is getting heavy and you want to shave off some HTTP requests. You can do this by caching. I usually use caching mostly on the templates so that every new UI, you don't need to load again from the server. You can do this by storing stuff in an object. you can go a little further and use the browser's [localStorage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) when available.

Caching isn't all for the network. Let's say you have some complex calculations you want to use later, or some text from an unfinished form, use the cache for that too.

### Avoid HTTP requests (or at least lighten them up)

While lightening up your app by using AJAX, you will inevitably be tempted to use AJAX just about anywhere - don't abuse it. Often times i see people who aggressively poll the server (every half-second or less). This not only strains the server (too many requests), but also the browser (wasting processing cycles) and the network (bandwidth). There are several practices done these days to avoid added HTTP requests:

- [Image Spriting](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) - The art of placing a lot of images into one image and using background-position to change the image. Surely beats 100 individual HTTP requests
- [Use JSON](http://json.org/) for textual data - AJAX was meant to use XML.. then came along JSON that was a fat-free, platform-independent format of strucured data.
- Do not return HTML-formatted data - With exemption of templates, which are HTML *strings*, you should never return HTML-formatted data over the wire. Have JS do JSON+templates on the client-side instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a similar app (Lightweight CMS)

In my view the approach you take will be dependent on the complexity of data that you are sending from the server > manipulating on the client side > and returning back to the server and db.

The cms that I'm working on is very basic and does not require heavy-duty manupulation on the client side. TinyMCE is as far as it will go.

Initially I was building the client admin area by `echo`ing `<input>` from php and then collecting the data by parsing the DOM, converting to JSON and AJAX it back to the server ([I found this code very helpful](http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/3/))
That of course required the user to hit "save" after editing or adding new data.

I later on decided that I needed something even more responsive and simpler than that so I'm now re-implementing everything for [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html) which AJAXes the data as soon as the client hits "OK" on that particular field. No "main save" required.

To conclude it's really an area that is pretty uncharted. I mean, it appears to me that people in the industry do not like to blur that line between back-end and front-end and find "one solution" that will do the entire DB>SERVER>CLIENT>SERVER>DB operation.

I'd love to see how you solved your problem.

Just my 2 cents.